# How to query with dates from SQL Server after today's date

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to query my database with ADO.NET

```
string con = "Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx\\SqlExpress;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=ID;Password=xxxxx;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);

using (connection)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Gigs where Date >= GetDate()";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    da.SelectCommand = command;

    connection.Close();

    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    gigs.DataSource = ds;
    gigs.DataBind();
}
```

The code executes fine, but it shows incorrect values. I was expecting to see only dates after today. Yet, I see values from the past and future. It's as if the query is simply `SELECT * from Gigs`

In SQL Server, the column `Date` is of type `date`.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct way to get rows from tomorrow and forward :

```
SELECT * FROM Gigs 
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(getdate() + 1 as date)
```

This would also work

```
[Date] >= DATEADD(d, datediff(d, 0,getdate()),1)
```

Using DATEDIFF will make the expression non-sargable, resulting in bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189794.aspx).

Change your string query as follows.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Gigs where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), [Date]) > 0";
```

This will select the rows which the Date column is newer than today's date.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Gigs WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date, 111) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),111)"
```